# Regarding edge triggering and level triggering in flip flops

Tags: circuits

After reading different books,I have understood what is edge triggering and level triggering.But I fail to understand in edge triggering how input is only taken during the falling edge or the rising edge of the clock and why input is not taken by the circuit when the clock is actually staying high?As when clock is high,the flip flop should be enabled ,so it should take the input when it is high as well,but it only takes input when it is rising or falling.
How does the circuit understand when to take the input?

Comment: Maybe show the circuit of the flip flop you are considering.

Comment: Have you looked at how these registers work exactly inside?

Comment: I am in general talking about flip flops.

Comment: Could be a jk flip flop or a t flip flop

Comment: If we consider a jk flip flop and how will the circuit know which trigger to consider?

Comment: All edge triggers ignore level after threshold is passed **by design.** Then must toggle and repeat edge to latch the input next time. That’s how sync operations are done.  How is another question using transmission gates and feedback.

Comment: Thats what my question is.How do they ignore other levels?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a teaching website. The (maybe unsatisfactory) answer is: look up how a register is build from transmission gates and how these work together to make edge triggered FF's. I have seem animations about that on the www but it might take some searching.

Comment: examine the SN74112 FF schematics. Basically you have a digital sample-hold behavior. A wild schematic, from what I recall.

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of understanding, you can think of an edge-triggered flip-flop as being constructed from two level-sensitive latches. One latch holds when the clock is high and the other holds when the clock is low. The Q output from the first latch is connected to the D input of the second. The D input to the first latch is the D input to the flip-flop, and the Q output of the second latch is the Q output of the flip-flop.

One of these latches is always transparent and one is always holding, regardless of the **level** of the clock signal. So, the Q output of the flip-flop can change value only at the instant in time when the clock signal changes value.